# Create XML file from perl hash

Tags: xml, perl, xpath, hash

I have a URL which returns me a array of String in perl (a hash) . I need to write these string array as xml file . How can i do that ..
i have basically 
step1 : get perl hash

```
my @xml = $phone->getXml();
```

step 2: iterate through the perl hash and add the elements in array as xml as it is.

```
 my $writer = new XML::Writer();
```

Instead of adding start and end tag ...
i want to add the elements in the array to a file and save it 
something like:

```
foreach my $Line (@xml) {
  # some writer parameter which can write it to file and save as "my.xml"
  writer->
}
```

I am new to perl ..can some one help me in step 2 pls ..

Comment: What does the schema of the XML you output need to look like? What XML element would you put each array element into?

Comment: Do you have an array or a hash??? You keep switching between the two

Comment: i have a array .In to the array , each line of a xml are added and sent back as a response for a http request .so if i add all the elements of the array that will form a xml for me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the emptyTag method:

```
for my $line (@xml) {
  $writer->emptyTag($line); # Just an empty tag
}
for my $line (@xml) {
  $writer->emptyTag($line, 'someattr' => 'someval'); # Empty tag with attributes
}
```

Answer (score 1):

"XML" is an incomplete description of a format. This would generate XML from a hash:

```
my $writer = XML::Writer->new();
$writer->startTag("root");

for my $key (keys(%hash)) {
   $writer->dataElement("attr", $hash{$key}, name => $key);
}

$writer->endTag("root");
$writer->end();
```